# Prove: a set of functions is closed if it contains the pointwise limit and converges uniformly to it

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

When applying the Arzela Ascoli theorem, I am little bit confused as to what needs to be done to show that a set of functions in $C_0([a,b])$ is closed.

Sifting through MSE I found a claim that :

> "a set of functions is closed if it contains the pointwise limit and
>   converges uniformly to it"

Is this statement true? What is the motivation behind it and can someone provide a reference to or a proof of the above?

Comment: $C_0 [a,b]$ is a normed space. How do you define "a closed set" in a normed space?

Comment: @user251257 Don't know, can you help?

Comment: You surely have some lecture notes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $C$ of a normed space $X$ is closed iff convergent sequences of elements of $C$ have their limits in $C$. In other words, convergent sequences in $C$ cannot escape $C$ (hence, the name closed.)

In the case of $C[a,b]$, a sequence $\{f_n \}\subset C[a,b]$ converges to $f\in C[a,b]$ iff 
$$
         \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \|f-f_n\|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)-f_n(x)| = 0.
$$
This is equivalent to uniform convergence of $\{ f_n\}$ to $f$.

If you have an equicontinuous set $\mathcal{E}$ of functions in $C[a,b]$, then pointwise convergence of a sequence $\{ f_n \}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ implies uniform convergence.

Comment: Thank for an actual answer on stackexchange these days! Can you give an example of a closed set? Thanks!

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows : An example: The set of all functions $f \in C[a,b]$ that vanish at $a$ and are Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant bounded by $M$. That is, $|f(x)-f(y)| \le M|x-y|$.